# Public remoted methods not allowed in global components

Tags: apex, visualforce, global-actions

I am getting this error in my building of exchange code: 
FTR.JobsHelper: line 217, column 46: Public remoted methods not allowed in global components

Here is my scenario. I am getting quite confused here:

1. We have two code packages, one is base package, the other is exchange package. What we usually do is packaging the base package in a pkg org and push the changes into exchange org. JobsHelper is in our base package. We build fine in pkg org. But after pushing code into exchange org, the build there fails. I have updated the exchange org with latest code.
2. We don't have any global component in our base org. I checked every apex:component tag in base package. None of them has explicitly defined access attribute. And the default value of access attribute is public.
3. I searched across the project about the usage of function defined at Line 217. But it is only used by two other remote actions which are not used in any iframe or global scenarios. And those two methods haven't got build errors.
4. JobsHelper is not a controller class. Instead, it is a helper class used by some controllers.

I am totally lost here. What can be the possible reason of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got that passed.

Not sure whether it is due to this summer's release or not, but it seems to be new to me. We can't define methods as @RemoteAction in non-controller class (and called by some controller @RemoteAction methods) any more. Anyway, we shouldn't be doing that though.

Comment: Didn't get your point. Can you make it more clear?